# What is wrong with this java generic method syntax

Tags: java, generics

I've the following classes

KeyValue.java

```
package test;

public class KeyValue<T> {
    private String key;

    private T value;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Reader.java

```
package test;

public interface Reader<T> {
    <S extends T> S read(Class<S> clazz);
}
```

Test.java

```
package test;

import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<KeyValue<Object>> list = find(KeyValue.class, new Reader<KeyValue<Object>>() {

            @Override
            public <S extends KeyValue<Object>> S read(Class<S> clazz) {
                return null;
            }
        });
    }

    public static <T> List<T> find(Class<T> targetClass, Reader<T> reader) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Here the method call `find(......)` is failing at compile time with error message

> The method find(Class, Reader) in the type Test is not applicable for the arguments (Class, new Reader>(){}).

This method has to return object of type `List<KeyValue<Object>>`.

What is wrong with this design and how to fix this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find`defines T and T (in first and second arg) to be of same type - your call to `find` uses the type `Object` in the first arg and the Type `KeyValue<Object>`in the second arg.

Either use two different type identifiers (e.g. T and X, i.e. `public static <T, X extends T> List<T> find(Class<T> targetClass, List<X> reader)`  ) in your `find` declaration or repair your call to `find`.

Comment: I've changed it, it was a mistake from my part. Now both are of type `KeyValue`.

Comment: No, still it has the error `The method find(Class<T>, Reader<T>) in the type Test is not applicable for the arguments (Class<KeyValue>, new Reader<KeyValue<Object>>(){})`

Comment: As you see from the Error message. java takes the first T as `<KeyValue>` and the second T as `<KeyValue<Object>`  - So they are not identical -- Perhaps change your signature to  `find(Class<X extends T> targetClass, Reader<T> reader)`  or to `find(Class<T> targetClass, Reader<X super T> reader)` depending on what you want to express (I assume the first).

Comment: Do KeyValue<Object> and KeyValue.class share the inheritance hierarchy that you've implied above?

Answer (score 1):

you want to get a list of your class KeyValue from your method find
but u defined it as  List note that it is a list of T not KeyValue
change ur method declaration to be as follows

```
private static <T> List<KeyValue<T> > find(Class<KeyValue> aClass, Reader<KeyValue<T> > reader) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

i think this is what u want

Answer (score -1):

Try to declare `Test` as

`public class Test<T> {`.